# Copy image files to phone storage

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I copy the image files  from my resource directory to documents directory?

This is I've tried so far, this is working but the copied image file is not formatted as image file, so I can't use it.

```
local path = system.pathForFile( "mypicture.png", system.ResourceDirectory )
local cfile = assert(io.open(path, "rb"))

if cfile then
    local imagedata = file:read("*a")
    io.close(file)

    local pathTo = system.pathForFile("mypicture.png", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open( pathTo, "w")

    file:write( imagedata )
    io.close( file )
    file = nil
else
    return nil
end
```

Any other way to copy images from the resource directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
--checking if file exist
function doesFileExist( fname, path )

    local results = false

    local filePath = system.pathForFile( fname, path )

    --filePath will be 'nil' if file doesn't exist and the path is 'system.ResourceDirectory'
    if ( filePath ) then
        filePath = io.open( filePath, "r" )
    end

    if ( filePath ) then
        print( "File found: " .. fname )
        --clean up file handles
        filePath:close()
        results = true
    else
        print( "File does not exist: " .. fname )
    end

    return results
end

--copy file to another path
function copyFile( srcName, srcPath, dstName, dstPath, overwrite )

    local results = false

    local srcPath = doesFileExist( srcName, srcPath )

    if ( srcPath == false ) then
        return nil  -- nil = source file not found
    end

    --check to see if destination file already exists
    if not ( overwrite ) then
        if ( fileLib.doesFileExist( dstName, dstPath ) ) then
            return 1  -- 1 = file already exists (don't overwrite)
        end
    end

    --copy the source file to the destination file
    local rfilePath = system.pathForFile( srcName, srcPath )
    local wfilePath = system.pathForFile( dstName, dstPath )

    local rfh = io.open( rfilePath, "rb" )
    local wfh = io.open( wfilePath, "wb" )

    if not ( wfh ) then
        print( "writeFileName open error!" )
        return false
    else
        --read the file from 'system.ResourceDirectory' and write to the destination directory
        local data = rfh:read( "*a" )
        if not ( data ) then
            print( "read error!" )
            return false
        else
            if not ( wfh:write( data ) ) then
                print( "write error!" )
                return false
            end
        end
    end

    results = 2  -- 2 = file copied successfully!

    --clean up file handles
    rfh:close()
    wfh:close()

    return results
end

--copy 'readme.txt' from the 'system.ResourceDirectory' to 'system.DocumentsDirectory'.
copyFile( "readme.txt", nil, "readme.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory, true )
```

this is the reference of the code http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html#copying-files-to-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code, `local imagedata = file:read("*a")` must be `local imagedata = cfile:read("*a")` same in the next line.

Other than that, the code looks valid and should work fine.

Comment: yes it works fine but the copied file is not formatted as .png, I only change `local file = io.open( pathTo, "w")` to `local file = io.open( pathTo, "wb")`